# Understanding simulation output: should the total dipole moment be the sum of its components?

Tags: dipole, molecular-dynamics, dipole-moment

I am trying to understand output from a simulation.  I want to calculate a total dipole moment.  This is the output I have for an example time step (I assume the three columns correspond to x, y, and z components:

```
MM DIPOLE [BERRY PHASE](A.U.)|           -3.333675  0.611131  1.550260
MM DIPOLE [BERRY PHASE](Debye)|          -8.473356  1.553341  3.940367
MM DIPOLE [BERRY PHASE] DERIVATIVE(A.U.)| 0.001417 -0.000391  0.002342
```

My question, which may be quite silly, is: is the total dipole moment simply the sum of its components; i.e., from my example above in Debye, (-8.473356 + 1.553341 + 3.940367)?

I ask because output from another simulation based on a different code provides the total dipole moment AND its components.  The sum of the components is not equal to the total.  For example:

```
  Dipole moment [Debye]
    X=    2.63551423 Y=  -18.81557012 Z=   11.26699720     Total=     22.08883972
```

So either there is a bug in that code or there's something simple I don't understand about how to calculate the total dipole moment from its components.  I can't find anything online about how to deal with this, possibly because this is not my field and I'm using the wrong search terms.  I would be very grateful if someone would please point me in the right direction.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could indicate (much) more about the context of the calculation and which simulations programs were used. Otherwise it is very difficult to comment anything on it which could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dipole moment is a vector, and hence the magnitude of the total dipole moment will be the square root of the sum of squares of its components.

Comment: Thank you very much, Hari.  I feel silly, but I'm very grateful!  Sorry, my reputation is not high enough to vote you up.